# How do we declare wires (interconnections in a digital circuit) when we want to use them in an always block?

Tags: verilog

I want to declare a wire and also i want to use it in an always block. This wire is the output of a bcd adder which goes to a decoder as an input. How should I declare it? `wire reg A`, `reg A`, `Output reg A`, `input reg A`?

Comment: Can you show a code example, of what your trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

declare it as Output reg A. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a wire having a value driven on to it then you can not override the value.

You can use the value in an always block. If you are setting a value from and only from the always block declare as a `reg`.

```
wire dout;
reg  dat;
modulex instance_1 (.dout( dout) );

always @* begin
  dat = dout ;
end
```

NB: in modulex dout may be declared as a wire or a reg, it is specific to the module and does not have to maintain 'type' across hierarchy.